# How can I draw a dashed line in PHP ImageMagick?

Tags: php, drawing, imagick

I'm trying to draw a dashed line using PHP Imagick.  This code produces a solid line:

```
$line = new ImagickDraw();
$line->setStrokeWidth(3);
$line->setStrokeDashArray([10, 10]);
$line->line(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

`setStrokeDashArray()` seems to work for outlines on `ImagickDraw::rectangle()` but not `ImagickDraw::line()` drawings.  Is there any way to draw simple dashed lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a nice dashed line without a solid line inside of it, set the fill color to opacity of zero (the actual color choice doesn't matter so long as the opacity value is a `0`), and then don't forget to set a stroke color.

A working example (with an added debugging to browser dump):

```
$line = new ImagickDraw();
$line->setStrokeColor('rgb(0, 0, 0)');
$line->setFillColor('rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');
$line->setStrokeWidth(3);
$line->setStrokeDashArray([10, 10]);
$line->line(0, 0, 100, 100);

// for debugging, output to browser:
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(200, 200, 'rgb(230, 230, 230)');
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$image->drawImage($line);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
exit;
```

Debug output result:

[image: Debug Output Example]